# change header excel export php laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4vkF.jpg

Here's what I have when trying to export it. It uses the attribute key by default. I want to change it into my own headers. For example payStatus to payment.

Here's my code:

```
public function exportReferral($sourceRef){
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start(); //At the very top of your program (first line)
    \Excel::create('ViecBonus ' . 'referal report', function($excel) use ($sourceRef) {
            $excel->sheet('ViecBonus Data', function($sheet) use ($sourceRef) {
                $sheet->fromModel($sourceRef);
            });
    })->export('xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
\Excel::create('ViecBonus ' . 'referal report', function($excel) use ($sourceRef) {
    $excel->sheet('ViecBonus Data', function($sheet) use ($sourceRef) {
        $sheet->appendRow(['some', 'custom', 'headers', 'here']);
        foreach ($sourceRef as $source) {
            $sheet->appendRow((array)$source);
        }
    });
})->export('xlsx');
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for transforming data before passing it to excel: `YourModel::select(['real_column as heading_name'])`, then your final file heading will be not `real_column` but `heading_name`.